# rails javascript - two select boxes with same category but selection of one value does not show in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

i got a form having **two select box** populated from the **same category model**.

```
<%= collection_select(:c, :id1, @categories, :id, :name) %>

<%= collection_select(:c, :id2, @categories, :id, :name) %>
```

Now is there any way to ensure that only one of the category be selected from any one of the select boxes at any instance.

like, if one selects "books" from the **first select box**, *second select box* do not show the "books" value and vice versa, or 
if one selects "music" from the **second select box**, *the first* does not show "music" in its values, and vice versa.

i.e., the selection of categories, at any instance, be completely unique.

i believe this requires the help of javascript but can this be solely done in the controller or does it require combo of both??

Answer (score 1):

You can make this without controller if you want. make jquery on change function which will be hide current option in second select. remember to prevent to be only one hide option in select

example:

```
  $("#c_id1").change(function(){
    $("#c_id2 option:hidden").show();
    if($(this).val().length ){
      $("#c_id2 option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").hide();
    }
  });
  $("#c_id2").change(function(){
    $("#c_id1 option:hidden").show();
    if($(this).val().length ){
      $("#c_id1 option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").hide();
    }
  });
```

something like this will be working. good will be refactor this. You should add prompt to collection_select to good work it because on the begining have the same without this change.

Comment: can you help with an example?

Comment: okay i have this extra complexity of css3 select box replacement. that nice little drop down is not forcing this behaviour. what can be done about this - http://jsfiddle.net/74LFD/9/

Comment: pls chk dis out - http://jsfiddle.net/6eCFz/. how can i make it work for dropdown like these?

Comment: jQuery change function not working because select is replaced by something other in your js. Why you made it? If only for look you can change select in css.

Comment: i am trying to build a custom styled dropdown. i thot this shud work as is. how can i make it work. i tried to include "ul" and "li" in place of "c_id", but its not working.